# Have a subquery inside the FROM part of query use info from another table inside the same FROM table list

Tags: sql, database

I don't know if I've explained it well enough, but I think I have an odd problem here.

I need to use my two queries as tables such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ...) query1, 
     (SELECT * ... FROM ... WHERE query1.col = mycol) query 2,
     table1 table1,
     table2 table2,
WHERE query1.something = table1.something
AND query1.otherthing = query2.otherthing
AND query2.something = table1.something
AND query.otherthing = table2.otherthing
```

Is something like this possible without nesting query1 again as a subquery into query2?

Comment: No this isn't explained well enough, but you're probably looking for something that can easily be joined.

Comment: It would be easier if you showed the queries, there is a possibility that this could be rewritten.

Comment: Other than that, what you are looking for is often refered to as derived tables, that can be used in exactly the same way as a regular table (in most databases that is). So yes, it is possible to do it the way you describe, but as mentioned above, chances are big that there's probably a more efficient way to do so.

Comment: You probably need a join. Can you show us the full query that works? Or an example of the data and the result.

Comment: The query is huge. The problem that I have with a join is that I'll get more rows than I actually want. I'd just like to filter that on my second query, from values for the first one. I'll update my query to a mroe precise one.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the subqueries have a field in common you should use a join like below. In this example there really should be any of this subquery nonsense, though, just join the tables together and be judicious with your WHERE clauses and join types to get just the information you want:

```
    SELECT foo2.A, foo2.B, bar2.C, bar2.D
FROM (
    SELECT A, B
    FROM foo
    ) AS foo2
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT A, C, D
    FROM bar
    ) AS bar2
ON foo2.A = bar2.A
```

Comment: You are missing the aliases for the derived tables (foo and bar)